# Changing the value of x-editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I have a few hyperlinks that I use with x-editable. They basically represent the size of a resizable div. Now when I resize the div, I'm setting the text of the `<a>` elements to display the new size. The problem is when I then click the hyperlinks and x-editable comes in the initial value of the input is not changed according to the new text value of the corresponding `<a>` element.

So if the initial div size is 400x400 and I resize it to 600x400 then when I click to edit the width, the initial textbox value is still 400.

```
function updateDivSize(div) //this is called whenever the div is being resized
{
    //$(context).find(".width-editable").editable('setValue', $(div).width());
    //$(context).find(".height-editable").editable('setValue', $(div).height());
    $(context).find(".width-editable").text($(div).width());
    $(context).find(".height-editable").text($(div).height());
}
```

Now if I call `.editable()` on the a elements again each time it works fine, but the problem is that I lose all of the other settings of the x-editable, which I'd like to keep. Is there any way I can do this without calling `.editable()` again with all of the other settings every time I resize the divs ?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/9955/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload the X-editable function, but before you can du that you need to destroy it like this:

```
$(".width-editable").editable('destroy');
$(".height-editable").editable('destroy');
```

I have edited your JSFiddel, please see the new one here: http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/9957/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was a better solution than reloading it every single time.