# x-editable won't drop/change value?

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I'm using `X-editable` to edit some text/values.

```
<a href='#' id='anstDat' class='editUsrProfile' data-name='anstDat' data-type='text' data-pk='' data-url='update.php'></a></td>
```

I'm setting the `data-pk` and `<a>TEXT</a>` with Jquery.

```
$('#anstDat').text(result[0].anstDat); //Tried using .val(..)
$('.editUsrProfile').attr('data-pk', usr);
```

I'm launching the `editable` with a click eventlistener:

```
$('.rowUsr').on('click', function(){
    $('#anstDat').text(result[0].anstDat); //Tried using .val(..)
    $('.editUsrProfile').attr('data-pk', usr);
    $('.editUsrProfile').editable();
});
```

So, i click one usr. (.rowUsr)
A modal is shown with usr details.
Here i have my link "anstDat" connected with editable.
When i press the link, editable prompts it´s popup and you can edit the text i was clicking.

But when i close that modal, and click another usr (rowUsr), and click the link again, the text in editables prompt is not as the text i clicked, but it´s the text from the first usr i clicked.

Somehow, editable saves the text/value, and when i once again run the "on click event" and assign editable to ".editUsrProfile" the old value is still there.

[image]

Do i need to kill/destroy editable to get the new values to be shown in editables prompt?

I was thinking editable will re-run, when i load it up once more?

**EDIT**
From docs:

```
Initial value of input. If not set, taken from element's text.
Note, that if element's text is empty - text is automatically generated from value and can be customized
```

Comment: Looks like you have to run the destroy method first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33897411/1839532